# Pageview.builder overlapping effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I'm coding a quiz app. I want to achieve this. Everything is okay but the overlapping effect doesnt. I'm using pageview.builder to navigate between pages. How can i achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: try to use stack widet

Comment: I did but it doesnt effect with pageview.builder. I dont know maybe i couldn't achieve it:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wish to have a carousel effect for your question cards.
A simple solution would be using ListView horizontally, also there are some packages that you would like to check, for example;

1. flutter_swiper
2. carousel_slider